# Switch to Nora mid game?

Tags: fallout-4, mods

In Fallout 4 (PC), is there a way to switch to play as Nora, mid game, after you've already been playing as Nate?

Will this break anything?

Comment: You take the risk of breaking things when you install mods.

Comment: @MattR yes I'm aware. Keyword being "risk".

Comment: open console command and type showlooksmenu 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using console:

Press the console button (usually its the "~") and type: **"sexchange"** to change your gender. You can change your look either again via console (I believe it is "**showlooksmenu player 1**") or visit a doctor in Diamond City.

I've tried this in the past (although relatively early in the game), there were no consequences.

Comment: the Gender specific perks like black widow or aqua lad don't transfer when you change sex. Something to keep in mind.